# Gutenberg javascript get media srcset

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, srcset

In WordPress it is easy to get an images `srcset` and `sizes` as saved in WordPress using the [`wp_get_attachment_image_srcset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_srcset/) function. I need to have that functionality on the block-editors side in javascript / react. Is that possible?

What I expect is a function that accepts a media id and returns the srcset somehow. If that is not possible, how could I implement a rest api endpoint for doing that? Or is there another way to pipe the function values from php to js?

For some reasons which are not relevant here, I cannot use dynamic php blocks.

Comment: What is the use case? Do you want to add this functionality to existing blocks or you're trying to develop new blocks?

Comment: Its for New Blocks. But i dont want to use dynamic Blocks PHP frontend

Answer (score 4):

I've share my solution here because I've see this post by searshing a solution for a similar problem : I was looking for a solution to get the srcset attribute and the complete generated 'img' tag but from the 'media' object returned by MediaReplaceFlow component (not only by attachment ID). It's probably adaptable to your problem by getting the media object with `wp.data.select( 'core').getMedia(media_id)`.

This media object already contain a 'sizes' array with URL of image in some image sizes. but it's not sufficient because it's hard to build srcset ans size attribute for image tag. So, after many research, I've found a very helpfull php filter : `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js`

so with this filter, I've writed this PHP code :

```
function imageTagForJs( $response, $attachment ) {
    foreach ( $response['sizes'] as $size => $datas ) {
      $response['sizes'][$size]['tag']    = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, $size );
      $response['sizes'][$size]['srcset'] = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment->ID, $size );
    }
    return $response;
  }
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'imageTagForJs', 10, 2 );
```

Now, in the 'media' JS object, each sizes get two new properties : tag and srcset. I can now get my img tag in js by simply using `media.sizes.medium.tag`.

**Important :** By default, media.sizes array contain only builtin image sizes (thumbnail, medium, etc) but not custom image sizes. You can simply add custom sizes by using [`image_size_names_choose`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/image_size_names_choose) filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an AJAX request that will be calling the `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` on an attachment ID and return the result.

*This example uses `jQuery` from the default "Twenty Seventeen" theme*

#### Inside the child theme `functions.php` we define the AJAX WP method:

```php
add_action("wp_ajax_get_attachment_image_srcset", "get_attachment_image_srcset");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_attachment_image_srcset", "get_attachment_image_srcset");

function get_attachment_image_srcset() {

  // Get attachment ID from the request
  $attachment_id = $_REQUEST['attachment_id'];

  // Get attachment srcset
  $srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset($attachment_id);

  // Return JSON with the srcset and the attachment_id
  wp_send_json([
    'srcset' => $srcset,
    'attachment_id' => $attachment_id
  ]);
}
```

Inside *Block Editor*, you can add a custom HTML block using AJAX to fetch the attachment srcset using an attachment ID.

#### Block Editor custom HTML code block:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // On a button click
  $('.get-srcset a').on('click', function() {

    // Get the value of a text input to pass as attachment ID
    let attachmentId = $('#attachmentid').val();

    // Make the AJAX call
    jQuery.ajax({
      type : "post",
      dataType : "json",
      url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data : {
        action: "get_attachment_image_srcset",
        attachment_id : attachmentId
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // If we got an srcset
        if(response.srcset) {
          // Update the result element text with trhe srcset value or use srcset
          $('#result').text(response.srcset);
        }
        else {
          alert("No srcset")
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

This will update the `#result` element text to something like this:

```
https://wp.lytrax.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/3_ser_conv07-300x225.jpg 300w, 
https://wp.lytrax.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/3_ser_conv07-768x576.jpg 768w, 
https://wp.lytrax.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/3_ser_conv07.jpg 832w
```

You can check this working on this demo WP site: https://wp.lytrax.net/test-attachment-srcset/ (*Valid attachment IDs are 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10*)

Comment: Just wondering if it would better to use the WP REST API instead of the old admin-ajax? 
`url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed'`

Answer (score 2):

Im using this

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
import { select, useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const image = useSelect( () => select( 'core' ).getMedia( id ) );
```

and lodash

```
const thumbnail = get( image, [ 'media_details', 'sizes', 'medium', 'source_url' ] );
```

For more: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/image/image.js#L90

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

TO get the featured image first you need featured image id and then pass it to the getmedia function to get the media object. after getting media object you can get relevant items from the object.

```
const featuredImageId = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' )
.getEditedPostAttribute( 'featured_media' );

const media = featuredImageId 
? wp.data.select( 'core').getMedia( featuredImageId ) 
: null;

console.log(media);
```

Comment: That is not what I was asking for